# how can I fix this "E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease' is not signed." error

Tags: docker, debian

I just wonder I have seen a few similar questions and trying different solutions such us adding the list of sources into the sources.list file and removing/pruning images using docker commands but doesn't seem to work.

I am just building a new image and the code is like:

```
 && echo "I am here ------------------->>" \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y apt-utils  \
&& apt-get install -y build-essential \
&& apt-get autoremove -y \
&& apt-get upgrade -y \
&& apt-get install -y wget unzip \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& echo "------------------->>" \
&& cd /tmp \
&& wget --quiet --directory-prefix=/tmp https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/0.10.1/vault_0.10.1_linux_amd64.zip \
&& unzip vault*.zip \
```

but keep on getting the error below. Btw I am running on a mac.

Required [IP: 10.139.234.224 8080]
#16 0.426 E: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-backports/InRelease  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: 10.139.234.224 8080]
#16 0.426 E: The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease' is not signed.
#16 0.426 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: 10.139.234.224 8080]
#16 0.426 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease' is not signed.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease' is not signed.

Comment: The important bit is `407 Proxy Authentication Required [IP: 10.139.234.224 8080]` which indicates that you're behind a proxy which needs you to authenticate before it'll let you access outside resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing GPG keys with below command, before apt-get update

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y debian-archive-keyring && apt-get clean
```