# Debian issue with docker

Tags: docker, debian

I am trying to create a simple pdf text extractor using ocr but i am not able to.
i think the issue is that the debian server is down or something along those lines.

this is the Dockerfile::

```
# Dockerfile

FROM python:3.11.3


# Install Tesseract and poppler-utils
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
    tesseract-ocr \
    poppler-utils \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements.txt into the container at /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY extract_text.py /app/

# Specify the command to run on container start
CMD ["python", "./extract_text.py"]
```

this is what i am running on the terminal and its output::

```
juan@192 pdf_ocr_extractor % docker system prune -a -f
docker builder prune -a -f
docker build -t pdf_ocr_extractor .
docker run -v /Users/juan/Desktop/dev/code/pdf_ocr_extractor:/data pdf_ocr_extractor python extract_text.py /data/doc.pdf
Deleted build cache objects:
kgkkmlafdg6akei7qbtf1bmu5
xskqcqk4opazcyvgt3fxb64yo
13bcwdvd9ut7vfs2satvgq08j
vb7al8ahfvu8jt56qng0fl3rh
zor7s3yozjzpgjpdu7qdpmpam
hblvcrt146srhmr8auwq3le1k
30exdbkxsiz7spkzut7vivxc3
tbl3ja6j760iebspo2aj7upay
popyaa0t3nv198bbynarrnzbx
reo6ndn1n91u6y1ug5t7anec2
qkpqepkr00vpzqssgrrsmelwk

Total reclaimed space: 1.143kB
Total:  0B
[+] Building 4.1s (7/11)                                                                                                                docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 708B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.3                                                                                        3.4s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                           0.0s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11.3@sha256:3a619e3c96fd4c5fc5e1998fd4dcb1f1403eb90c4c6409c70d7e80b9468df7df                                  0.1s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.11.3@sha256:3a619e3c96fd4c5fc5e1998fd4dcb1f1403eb90c4c6409c70d7e80b9468df7df                                  0.0s
 => => sha256:de5aeca5458519a772e9b344d3c1ac16a1be52eab179cf2a28a31382dd1018f1 2.01kB / 2.01kB                                                          0.0s
 => => sha256:1918a277862c33ee6f35b696867ca414a014f2b63f1e257986a3f480c9da5edc 7.54kB / 7.54kB                                                          0.0s
 => => sha256:3a619e3c96fd4c5fc5e1998fd4dcb1f1403eb90c4c6409c70d7e80b9468df7df 2.14kB / 2.14kB                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 669B                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [2/6] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated     tesseract-ocr     poppler-utils     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/  0.5s
------                                                                                                                                                       
 > [2/6] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated     tesseract-ocr     poppler-utils     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:            
0.368 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
0.386 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
0.387 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]
0.445 Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
0.445   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.482 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
0.482   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.518 Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
0.518   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.525 Reading package lists...
0.534 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.534 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
0.534 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.534 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease' is not signed.
0.534 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.534 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease' is not signed.
------
Dockerfile:7
--------------------
   6 |     # Install Tesseract and poppler-utils
   7 | >>> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
   8 | >>>     tesseract-ocr \
   9 | >>>     poppler-utils \
  10 | >>>     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  11 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated     tesseract-ocr     poppler-utils     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
Unable to find image 'pdf_ocr_extractor:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for pdf_ocr_extractor, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
juan@192 pdf_ocr_extractor %
```

I am also getting some Docker issues but i am not sure why i am getting them.

I found this stackoverflow question that is very similar but it has no answers::
[how can I fix this "E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease' is not signed." error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74036222/how-can-i-fix-this-e-the-repository-http-deb-debian-org-debian-bullseye-upd)

Comment: I have just executed the first part of your Dockerfile on my machine and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i was clearing all the data in the containers and images and i was still getting the error.

after @Pino posted that it worked on his machine i looked at the docker configurations and increased the size of the resources and it worked